# AngularJS dynamic template with input

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to compare two passwords with javaScript, but I have two issues.

Here is my plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/SWJIQs5zSkFCoHMPoOtK

When I enter no passwords, the I have the message "Passwords are equals" but there is no password entered and in my *comparePassword* factory, I wrote the case if password is empty.

```
if (password1 === password2 && password1 !== null && password1 !== '')
```

The other thing I want to do is to make the javaScript template appear and not :

```
{restrict: 'EA', template: '<span color="green">Passwords match each other</span>'}
```

I don’t know how to do this because the solutions I founded where using JQuery and I do not want to.

EDIT: I find this solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/kaYywF1PdakFlq3TMZF8?p=preview

BUT, when there is no passwords, the message is "Passwords match", although it is false.

Thanks

Comment: How about using form validation such as in this post (with included plunker)? http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/10/13/confirm-password-validation-in-angularjs.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I do not really understand how this script works. Moreover it using scope, and I do not want to use scope. I do not understand why it is useful to integrate ngModel in a script.js.

Comment: I think this [dynamicTemplate service](https://github.com/BurakAkyildiz/angularJs-dynamic-conditional-templates) helpfull for this case.